# Android. How do I keep a button displayed as PRESSED until the action created by that button is finished? Activated/Selected not usable

Tags: android, button, selection, remoteview

I want to keep a ImageButton with a state-list drawable in a "Wait-for-Action-Finished" state as long the action was not done.

I've seen the other topics around this problem. But in my case the other solutions are not working for me because:

- I'm using the layout (which contains the buttons) in a RemoteView too (but not only there)
- I'm using the same layout in a recyclerview with Multi-Selection capabilities. Therefore the activated/selected state is used by the multi-selector implementation and not possible for the state-list drawable except it was not propagated from selected-item to child views => my butotns
- using custom state not working with RemoteViews
- Using ToogleButton not possible, because setEnabled is not available for Buttons/ToggleButtons/CompoundButtons in RemoteViews

It's not important that the "Wait-for-Action-Finished" drawable was shown in the RemoteView (but it would be nice...), but I don't want to duplicate the layout. It's okay if the Wait-State was shown in the RecyclerView items only.
But there it should work along with the Multiselector function.

I'm using an ImageButton because it can be disabled in a RemoteView (in opposite to Button/ToggleButton/CompoundButton in general).

any hints how I could solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've got it working by combining the selected and activated states.

My button looks like this:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/progress_small"           android:state_activated="true" android:state_selected="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/btn_bookmark_add_pressed" android:state_focused="true" android:state_pressed="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/btn_bookmark_add_pressed" android:state_focused="false" android:state_pressed="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/btn_bookmark_add_pressed" android:state_focused="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/btn_bookmark_add_normal"  android:state_focused="false" android:state_pressed="false" />
</selector>
```

And my button.onClicklistener looks like this:

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    if (v.isActivated() && v.isSelected()) {
        return;
    }
    v.setActivated(true);
    v.setSelected(true);
    AppController.getJobManager().addJob(new Job()));
}
```

This way it won't collide neither with "click the itemView", where selected state will be propagated to all child views (inclusive my buttons) nor with activate the "multi-selection" feature where the activated state will be propagated to all child views.

After the job is finished it will notify (EventBus) the `RecyclerView` where the `ViewHolder` can reset both activated and selected state back to false.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to manually set the state of the button and keep it there. This solution will give you some insight [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29758073/android-change-button-color-when-clicked/29758200#29758200)

Answer (score 1):

After reading out your question The thing what I understand the solution will be like below.
First set the button.xml as below.Use it as drawable for that button.Each of the state btn_disabled or the btn_pressed is the drawable state of your button which is defined by you.

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/btn_disabled" android:state_enabled="false"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/btn_pressed" android:state_pressed="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/btn_pressed" android:state_selected="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/btn_default"/>
</selector>
```

Next use the code snippet below.

```
boolean checkActionOpen = false;
button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
 @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
         if(!checkActionOpen) {
             checkActionOpen = true;
             button.setSelected(true);
         }
    }
});
```

Then again where the work will go on after the finish you will set **checkActionOpen** as false and do the **button.setSelected(false);** action.